# How to use AT commands to detect if "RING" has ended

Tags: at-command, mscomm32

Is there a way to detect if the modem has stopped ringing? I am using an MSComm object to communicate with my phone via serial port. I know that MSComm has an event that can tell if the phone is ringing, but there is  no event to tell that the phone stopped ringing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check out +VRN and +VRA commands in the Hayes AT command set. They are timers which you can set to have the modem listen for time between rings.  If the time exceeds the timer, it will send the "OK" response.